# How to pass the CSRF Token in iFrame of Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, x-frame-options

I have made a site with django. I wish people can iframe my form and fill it to check the results. I have already tried by writing the following  code in settings.py

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM example.com'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['example.com']
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

But it won't work. Shows the following error. How can I solve this issue. Moreover, if I want to allow all user how to write Xframe options.

I am new to Django. I have tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621161/django-csrf-cookie-not-set-in-iframe-workaround-without-csrf-exempt)

[It shows iframe but when submit form it is showing this kind of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esBpq.png)